# Is it okay to perform numerical calculations on UI side?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

This question is more from a design perspective. While making a web application should I perform numerical calculations (a few of them atmost) on `javascript` (UI part) or on the server side ?

What can be advantages / disadvantages of each approach ?

Comment: If the calculations aren't significantly CPU intensive, I'd prefer to calculate on the client-side, for the sake of no lag before a UI update

Comment: Automated testing will be harder if you put logic on both sides, client and server. That and a lot more advantages and disadvantages are discussed [in a nice question on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252224/when-is-it-appropriate-to-do-calculations-in-front-end)

Comment: Well it completely depends on kind of applications you want to build. but in general intensive cpu calculations are generally done on server side only.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: "It depends"

If you are calculating something like age, you can do it in the client side, but if you are calculating something like currency, you should do it in server side with a BigDecimal because of it's precision.

Answer (score 0):

> **There is no silver bullet**

You may find either client or backend side calculation in many different software architectures. the thing you should consider is what is the type of you calculation.

Let me break it here for better decision making:

1. **simple calculation** : if the calculation does not involve many complex steps,so you can go ahead and do it on client-side but you should keep in mind do not scatter logic all-over as it raise the maintenance cost and effort.
2. **complex calculation** : imagine you need so many data to be received from backend before you do your calculation, or the calculation is a business related logic, or your calculation is cpu-intensive that not all your client devices (i.e. Mobile) can handle it, as a result it's better you gather all your calculation logic all in the back-end side.

Answer (score 0):

Rules of thumbs for me:

- If you are dealing with lots of data, have it on a server that does the calculation, usually your browser will start lagging and freeze. However you can start on the client side first, and if you see that your data is growing, thats only when i will consider having it on the server side, as optimise only when you need. Eg: Dashboard is a good example of having it on the server (calculate total orders amount, total orders in January..etc)
- If the for eg calculating total amount of an order, you need it on both client side and server side (Validate the total amount from server against client)